# SSIS - Derived Column - Substring/Charindex - Case when statement

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I've this SQL Code:

```
Select [Name] = case when CHARINDEX(''.'', [Name])>0 
                            then LEFT([Name],CHARINDEX(''.'', [Name])-1)
                        else [Name] end,
        [System] = case when reverse(SUBSTRING(REVERSE( System),1,CHARINDEX('':'', REVERSE(System)))) like '':'' 
                            then (  System + ''\'')
                        else    System end
```

And I'm creating my SSIS workflow in order to build my ETL using SSIS. To create the transformations above I'm using a Derived Column Object.
For the first statement I try this:

```
ISNULL(SUBSTRING([Name],1,FINDSTRING([Name],".",1) - 1)) ? [Name] : SUBSTRING([Name],1,FINDSTRING([Name],".",1) - 1)
```

But it gives me error...

How can I make that two transformations?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? what type of value are you getting in the Name column?

Comment: It don't gives me any result... ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Expression Task` to achieve this

- For `[Name]` expression you can use the following

  ```
  @[User::Name] = FINDSTRING( @[User::Name] ,".",1) == 0 ?  @[User::Name] : LEFT(SUBSTRING( @[User::Name] ,1,FINDSTRING( @[User::Name] ,".",1) ), LEN(SUBSTRING(@[User::Name] ,1,FINDSTRING( @[User::Name] ,".",1))) -1)
  ```

*`SUBSTRING` don't allow to subtract -1 from length you can use `LEFT` to achieve this*

- For `[System]` expression you can use the following

  ```
  @[User::System] = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::System]),1,FINDSTRING( REVERSE(@[User::System]),":",1))) == ":"  ? @[User::System] + "\\"    : @[User::System]
  ```

Comment: @PedroAlves happy to help. It is a useful question. I upvoted it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two variable like Name (String) and t (Int32).
2. Use two expression tasks

[image]

3. EXPR_Set_Flag_For_Dot: `@[User::t] = (FINDSTRING(@[User::Name], ".", 1) == 0 ? 0 :  1 )`
4. EXPR_Get_SubString: `FINDSTRING( @[User::Name] ,".",1) == 0 ?  @[User::Name] : SUBSTRING( @[User::Name] ,1,FINDSTRING( @[User::Name] ,".",1) - @[User::t] )`.

**Note:** In your expression you are using -1 in the SubString, when there is no dot (.) in the name, the expression will throw error. FindString will give 0 so 0-1 in the outer SubString is not allowed. The first expression already checks this and assigns @[User::t] with 0 when there is no dot, due to which 0-0 will not through error.

Comment: Top! :) The first statement is working perfectly :) For the second statment do you know how to use Reverse() function in SSIS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/reverse-ssis-expression